# How can I create a completion handler with admob interstital ads in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm trying to pause the background of my app (which is a game) when admob's interstitial ad is running. When the user decides to close the ad, then the game should resume. This would work best with a completion handler but GoogleMobileAds doesn't seem to offer one. Is there way to make one?

What the code would look like:

```
func gameDidEnd(relish: Relish) {
        view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        scene.stopTicking()

        let score: Int = Int(scoreLabel.text!)!

        if score > userHS {
            updateHighScore(score)
        }

        if (interstitial.isReady) {
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            interstitial = createAd()

            if interstitial.pressedCloseOnAd {
               scene.animateCollapsingLines(relish.removeAllBlocks(), fallenBlocks:
               relish.removeAllBlocks()) {
                relish.beginGame()
                getCurrentReward(user.ID)
            }
        }

        else {
            scene.animateCollapsingLines(relish.removeAllBlocks(), fallenBlocks:
            relish.removeAllBlocks()) {
            relish.beginGame()
            getCurrentReward(user.ID)
        }


    }
```

Also I'm running into the issue where I try to display an interstitial ad after they exit the game page with `tappedClose`. Originally, when `tappedClose` was called, `dismissViewControllerAnimated` would be called. If I try and run an interstitial ad before that, `dismissViewControllerAnimated` would just close out the ad. If I put the interstitial ad after `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, the ad never runs (because it is not in the window hierarchy).

Thanks for your help!

---

Updated

```
func interstitialWillPresentScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    scene.stopTicking()
    print("interstitialWillPresentScreen")
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!, relish: Relish) {
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scene.startTicking()
    getCurrentReward(user.relationshipID)
    print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
}

func gameDidEnd(relish: Relish) {
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    scene.stopTicking()

    let score: Int = Int(scoreLabel.text!)!

    if score > userHS {
        updateHighScore(score)
    }

    if (interstitial.isReady == false) {
        print("is not ready")
        scene.animateCollapsingLines(relish.removeAllBlocks(), fallenBlocks:
        relish.removeAllBlocks()) {
            relish.beginGame()
        }

        getCurrentReward(user.relationshipID)
    }

    else if (interstitial.isReady) {
        print("is ready")
        interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        interstitialWillPresentScreen(interstitial)
        interstitialDidDismissScreen(interstitial, relish: relish)
        interstitial = createAd()
    }
}
```

When the game ends, the console reads:

```
is ready
interstitialDidDismissScreen
2016-09-06 22:22:43.915 file[5321:347179] <Google> Request Error: Will not send request because interstitial object has been used.
is not ready
```

The last is not ready signifies that the game continued in the background even though when `gameDidEnd` was called, `interstitial.isReady` was true so it should've only ran the `else if` statement.

Comment: admob has a delegate protocol called `GADInterstitialDelegate`, you should be using `interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad:GADInterstitial)` to find when the user closes the ad

Comment: @Knight0fDragon What would I write inside of that? Or would I just leave it blank and replace the above `if interstitial.pressedClosedAd` with `interstitialDidDismissScreen(interstitial)`, making the program wait till it was dismissed?

Comment: you have `interstitialDidDismissScreen` call your completion block, you just need to get that block over to the view controller

Comment: The reason you are getting this `Request Error` is that because you already used the interstial that you are trying to present. Which means you already called the function `presentFromRootController` on this interstial object. You need to renew your interstial object after dismissing or using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code work this way I think:

1.Set your interstial ad's delegate to your class

2.Stop the game when you are presenting the interstial ad by this delegate method:

```
func interstitialWillPresentScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    // Stop the game
}
```

3.Resume your game after user closes the interstial ad with this delegate method:

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    // Resume the game
}
```

There are some other `GADInterstitialDelegate` methods you might want to check out, if you do refer to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/ad-events#registering_for_interstitial_events).

Comment: So what if I want to make an interstitial ad that runs after they exit the game? `interstitialWillPresentScreen` -> `//stop the game` limits this use of the function to only the game. Is there a way to make it so the app only runs that thread and pauses all other processes?

Comment: I updated my question, please refer to the code after the line.

Comment: I added a comment on the `Request Error` issue